# Parsing list of case classes

Tags: list, class, scala, parsing

I am fairly new to scala and I want to parse a list of case classes:

```
abstract class D
case class D0(a: Int, b: Int) extends D
case class D2(c: String, d: Int) extends D
case class D3(e: Int, f: String) extends D
case class D4(e: String, f: String, g: Int) extends D
```

I want to parse a instance of List[D]. 
There is a special order in the list which can be explained by BNF-like notation:

```
rep(D0 -> D4 -> rep(D2 -> opt(rep(d3))))
```

D0 is followed by D4 is followed by 1-n D2, each D2 followed by 1-n D3 and so on...

I want to create a List of type:

```
type T0 = (D0, D4, List[(D2, List[D3])])
```

All solutions I have found so far are ugly and statefull.
How would a experienced scala developer implement this ?

Thank You

Comment: What do you parse from? I.e., what is your input format?

Comment: A `List[D]` is not the same thing as your proposed structure. A list is a list. Your structure is something else.

Comment: The List[D] is imported from a file based legacy database with different record types implementing a hierarchical database model.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't look too ugly to me (assuming I understood the question correctly, this isn't commonly called parsing):

```
type T1 = (D2, List[D3])

// MatchError if the list doesn't look the way you expected
def matchList(l: List[D]): List[T0] = l match {
  case (d0: D0) :: (d4: D4) :: tail => 
    val (d2d3s, tail1) = matchD2D3s(tail)
    (d0, d4, d2d3s) :: matchList(tail1)
  case Nil => Nil
}

def matchD2D3s(l: List[D]): (List[T1], List[D]) = l match {
  case (d2: D2) :: tail =>
    val (d3s, tail1) = tail.span(_.isInstanceOf[D3])
    val (otherD2D3s, tail2) = matchD2D3s(tail1)
    ((d2, d3s) :: otherD2D3s, tail2)
  case l => (Nil, l) // no d2s
}
```

Comment: I still need to  verify the presented solution, maybe ok in this special case.Still new to functional scala it doesn't look very easy to me, especially if the number of cases will be increased.